# botão do popover bootstrap em jquery não mostra o conteúdo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, popover

Bom dia galera, estou tentando entender como funciona o popover do bootstrap, estou tentando utilizar em forma de botão pra eu entender como funciona mas isso está um segredo pra mim. Apesar de seguir tutoriais, ou indicações da documentação da página do bootstrap sobre o assunto, inclusive CTRL C... não funciona, queria um ajuda de como solucionar a minha dúvida e alcançar o que estou tentando executar, por favor.

Abaixo o código

```html
<!-->  
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Antic' rel='stylesheet'>  
    
==========:::::: CONTEÙDO DO TOPO DA PÀGINA ::::::========    
<-->


<footer>
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
          <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-4">Plug seu celular na moda</h1>
            <p>Atendimento das 10:00 às 22:10 de Segunda-feira à Sábado!
            <p>
            <table style="width:100%">
                <th>Politicas</th>
                <th>Serviços</th>
                <th>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(function () {
                    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
                  })
                })
                </script>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="container" data-toggle="popover" title="Informações" data-content="Lorem Ipsum" data-placement="top">Informações</button>
                </th>
              <tr>
                <td>Formas de Pagamento</td>
                <td>Prazo de Troca</td>
                <td>Troca de Películas</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Descontos</td>
                <td>Políticas de Troca</td>
                <td>Manutenção</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Sorteios</td>
                <td>Regulamento de Trocas</td>
                <td>Encomendas</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Fornecedores</td>
                <td>Reembolso</td>
                <td>Atendimento ao Cliente</td>
              </tr>
            </table>    
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert" id="copyright">
          <p>2018 Copyright © Website desenvolvido por Públio Elon.</p>
        </div>
      </footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para o uso de **Popovers**

1- Popover é uma biblioteca de terceiros, você precisa fazer a chamada [desse arquivo](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js) antes do arquivo do **JS** do bootstrap Da seguinte maneira :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

2- É necessário fazer a iniciação do **Popover** assim quando o documento for inciado, basta selecionar a sua `data-toggle` e fazer a chamada da função, da seguinte maneira: `$(document).ready(function(){  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()})`
 Desse modo, todos os elementos com esse atributo serão automaticamente reconhecidos.

3- É necessário a importação do [Jquery](http://code.jquery.com/) antes do fechamento da tag `body` página para os elementos funcionarem.

Abaixo contém um exemplo do seu funcionamento.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Título do Popover" data-content="Exemplo de Popover em ação!">Clique!</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Realmente amigo, o que você demonstrou estava correto, pois ao olhar o meu código percebi que a importação desta biblioteca tinha sido removida durante algumas alterações que fiz anteriormente: <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Que bom que foi útil para você. Abraços!